# string is null when posting from Angular to Web API?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

When I try to post a string to my web api, the value is null.  I have tried wrapping it in quotes, but it is still null.

AngularJS code:

```
return $http.post("http://localhost:59437/api/Recaptcha/Post", 
                                    vcRecaptchaService.getResponse());
```

Web Api code:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class RecaptchaController : ApiController
{
    public string Post([FromBody] string response)
    {
        return response;
    }
}
```

I also am not sure how this even works because, i don't have a response in my form body.  `vcRecaptchaService.getResponse()` just returns a response string and then I am going to send that to google's verify api to verify the recaptcha, so the [FromBody] part doesn't make sense to me if that is not part of the body

Comment: what `vcRecaptchaService.getResponse()` method does?

Comment: @PankajParkar - It returns a string response when you check the recaptcha checbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your post call should be sending data in json format like `{response: 'something'}`

```
  return $http.post("http://localhost:59437/api/Recaptcha/Post", 
       { response: vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() } //data 
  );
```

Comment: I tried this and I also tried doing `{ response: "'" + vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() + "'"}`, but it is still null

Comment: @xaisoft no need of single quotes, are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Just checked, no console error. I tried hard-coding a string instead of using `vcRecaptchaService.getResponse()`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: When I look at chrome's developer tools, I see the Request Payload set to the string, but when it hits the Api Controller action, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in quotes worked, but I had to do it just like this:

```
return $http.post("http://localhost:59437/api/Recaptcha/Post",
           '"' + vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() + '"'
        );
```